# Manually changing Google Custom Search's search box and button

Tags: google-custom-search

I want to make my own custom search box and button for GCSv2.
Here is my code:
(pastebin because I am too lazy to make my code look right)
http://pastebin.com/p4yThTma

And the code I want the search box and button to be linked too,
http://pastebin.com/SK1Df7rs

Answer (score -1):

i was trying to find a way to do it as well but i couldn't 
on google webpage there isn't enough information about modifying the GCSE
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element

i would like if someone already customize it to share it with us